# RegEx to match end of URL

Tags: regex

I'd like to match strings ending with /web/ or /mobile/

I wrote this RegEx:

> (/web/|/mobile/)$

but it's not working as expected, I tested with https://regex101.com/r/P2p4sa/1/

What am I missing? Are there any more clever expressions I could use?

Comment: [It works, you did not enable multiline option](https://regex101.com/r/P2p4sa/2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$` only matches the end of the whole input by default. Just enable "Multiline" in the flag options (right side of the regex input). This will let `$` match the end of each line.

When you use it in your code, setting the flag is only necessary if your input consists of multiple lines.